# app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug can't resolve

Tags: android

I have this error whenever i try to create an APK for the app.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/text/TextUtilsCompat.class

The app run in the android emulator , but when i try to build an apk i get this error.
i dont know what to change

here is the gradle code

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.companyname.gamename"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 23
    multiDexEnabled true

    ndk {
        moduleName "player_shared"
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        jni.srcDirs = []
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
compile files('libs/support-v4-19.0.1.jar')
compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
}
```

I tryed to clean rebuild an run the prject but i still have the same problem, 
I've read that it's depencdencies problem. but can't figure wich one to remove.

Comment: comment `compile files('libs/support-v4-19.0.1.jar')` and use `play-services:10.0.1` instead of `play-services:+`

Comment: Refactoring the library may help you resolve this issue. This may help in removing duplicate classes from the library or from the app module.

Answer (score 1):

First, never use a plus dependency.

```
services:+'
```

Also don't compile all the Play Services, only setup ones you really need.

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split

Secondly, stop using jar files and go find the correct libraries using Maven Central (or the supporting documentation for those libraries) and use the other way to  compile through Gradle.

Your jar files have overlapping classes and therefore you have errors

While you're at it...

- Dagger 1 is being deprecated for Dagger 2
- NineoldAndroids has stopped being maintained, so best to  find some other way to use the code you need it for
- Your support libraries need to match the compileSdk version